# CRUD code generation for an asp.net core single page application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, xamarin, visual-studio-code, rider

I want to create a Single Page Web Application (SPA) which works on asp.net core.
What i want to do is first create my data model (code first with entity framework).

Then i want to auto generate rest api and javascript stuff that will provide CRUD operation for all tables.

For listing page, i want progressive/infinite scrolling (no paging).

Is there a way to do this with Xamarin or Jetbrains Rider, or Visual Studio Code or should i have to write this code generator by myself ?

Thanks

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to define your database with a model and then make a rightlick to generate all the crud operations and a frontend to show it all? Something like that is not possible. You can generate your DB from a datamodel, but I am afraid that you have to write the rest for yourself...